# Angular-cli Error: Cannot find module '@ngtools/json-schema'

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I recently ran npm update in my project. After that completed, anytime i try to run ng serve I get a

> Error: Cannot find module '@ngtools/json-schema'

However in my node_modules file there is very clearly a @ngtools file present. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling angular-cli but still receive this error.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
"auth0-js": "^8.11.3",
"auth0-lock": "^10.24.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"chart.js": "^2.7.1",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},

  "devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "^6.0.92",
"codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
"karma": "~1.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.0",
"ts-node": "~2.0.0",
"tslint": "~4.5.0",
"typescript": "~2.2.0",
"webpack": "^3.8.1"
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Share your package.json file

Comment: There is no `@ngtools/json-schema` in your dependencies...

Comment: @user184994 I haven't had it in my list of dependencies previously and ng-cli ran fine

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install --save @ngtools/json-schema` to see if that works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see one possible mistake:

- Make sure you run `npm update --save` or no changes will be saved

If you still get the errors, follow these steps:

- `rm -rf node_modules`
- Delete `package-lock.json`
- `npm install`

Comment: thanks for the answer @austinthedeveloper. I am running windows so i had to find the equivalent of rm and -rf but it worked!

Comment: Drag and drop node_modules to trash can? ;)